# Progress Bar For Java Applet With Using All Browsers

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, browser

I want to add progress bar when the applet is loaded on all browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox , Internet Explorer , Safari, Opera) . I try to make this with javascript and html body onload method. I use below code..

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Your Title Here</title>
    </head>

   <script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script> 
  <script src="/jquery.browser.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script> 
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

//if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
//alert("firefox"); 
 //}



function init() {


var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;                    
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';                                                             
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor')>0;      
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;                                                                    
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || document.documentMode; 

if(isIE == 11)
{

if(document.applets[0].visibility="visible")
{
alert("Loading On Internet Explorer");
document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
}
}


if(isChrome == true)
{
//alert("Google Chrome");
if(document.applets[0].visibility="visible")
{
alert("Loading On Google Chrome");
document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
//alert("Loading On Google Chrome");
//alert("internet explorer");
//alert("Loading...");
//document.writeln( "User Agent        = " + navigator.userAgent );
//document.loading.visibility="hidden";
//document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
}
}




if(isFirefox == true)
{
//alert("mozilla firefox");
if(document.applets[0].visibility="visible")
{
alert("Loading On Mozilla Firefox");
document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
//alert("internet explorer");
//alert("Loading...");
//document.writeln( "User Agent        = " + navigator.userAgent );
//document.loading.visibility="hidden";
//document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
}
}


if(isSafari == true)
{
//alert("Safari");
if(document.applets[0].visibility="visible")
{
alert("Loading On Safari");
//alert("internet explorer");
//alert("Loading...");
//document.writeln( "User Agent        = " + navigator.userAgent );
//document.loading.visibility="hidden";
//document.all.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
}
}



 }





    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

      #loading {
        position:absolute;
        left:150;
        top:200;
      }

      #myapplet {
        position:absolute;
        left:10;
        top:10;
        visibility:hide;
      }

    </style>

    <body onLoad="init()">

      <div id="loading">
        <p>Loading  applet, please wait.</p>
      </div>


        <applet archive="app1.jar" code="app1.class" align="baseline" width="620" height="442">
          <p>Requires a browser that supports Java.</p>
        </applet>
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Above code works true on internet explorer but not work true on firefox and chromium. Progress Bar disappear when install plugin pop up message is shown in mozilla firefox before applet fully loaded. This progress bar must disappear after applet fully loaded. How can i do this with  mozilla firefox and google chromium correctly. Should i use  different codes for each browsers..

Comment: Each `if(document.applets[0].visibility="visible")` needs to be `if(document.applets[0].visibility === "visible")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to add progress bar **when the applet is loaded on all browsers**". With using javascript and html u can't understand applet is loaded  on browsers. You are dealing unnecessary things. I suggest you to read this discussion.[How To Show Progress Bar When The Java Applet Load On Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252599/how-to-show-progress-bar-when-the-java-applet-load-on-web-browser/25347919#25347919)